# set react 18next value inside state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

I did a dropdown using reactstrap and works ok, but now I'm trying to set a value of react-18next into my state for the value of dropDownValue.
The i18n works fine inside my render but I can 't access its values inside my state..
any ideas?
this is my code.
thank you in advance!

dropdownd.jsx:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import {
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class TopbarNavDashboards extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    dropDownValue: 'Home', // this must be  {t('app.home')}
    dropdownOpen: false,
  };

  static propTypes = {
    t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  toggle = () => {
    const { dropdownOpen } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !dropdownOpen,
    });
  };

  changeValue = (e) => {
    this.setState({ dropDownValue: e.currentTarget.textContent });
  };

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    const { dropdownOpen, dropDownValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <UncontrolledDropdown
        isOpen={dropdownOpen}
        toggle={this.toggle}
        className="topbar__nav-dropdown"
      >
        <DropdownToggle className="topbar__nav-dropdown-toggle">
          {dropDownValue} <MenuSwapIcon />
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu className="topbar__nav-dropdown-menu dropdown__menu">
          <DropdownItem onClick={this.changeValue}>
            <TopbarNavLink route="/home" title={t('app.home')}/>
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem onClick={this.changeValue}>
            <TopbarNavLink route="/github" title={t('app.github')} />
          </DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem onClick={this.changeValue}>
            <TopbarNavLink route="/proyects" title={t('app.proyects')} />
          </DropdownItem>
      </UncontrolledDropdown>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation('common')(TopbarNavDashboards);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think you can refer to props within the state object:

```js
state = {
  dropDownValue: this.props.t('app.home')
  dropdownOpen: false,
};
```